# How can I add keys to a list based on the size of the value of an ArrayListMultiMap?

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I have an ArrayListMultimap like

```
ArrayListMultimap<Long, String> multiMap =  ArrayListMultimap.create();

multiMap.put(100L,"test1");
multiMap.put(750L,"test0");
multiMap.put(50L, "test2");
multiMap.put(500L, "test3");
multiMap.put(200L, "test45");
multiMap.put(200L, "test000");
multiMap.put(60L, "test48");
```

which gives me `{50=[test2], 100=[test1], 500=[test3], 200=[test45, test000], 60=[test48], 750=[test0]}` .

I want to add all the keys to a list but the keys with multiple values need to be added based on the size of the value list. For example, in the above example, I want `200` to be added twice to the list since the size of its value is 2. I have tried using `ArrayList<Long> keyList = pathSizeMap.keySet()` but this gives me just the keys. 
How can I achieve this preferably using Java 8 streams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `keySet()` specifically says **Set** (as in the collection that has no duplicate entries). That's why you're getting a single copy of each key.

Instead of using `keySet()` just stream the **entries** and get the key of each one:

```
List<Long> list = multiMap.entries().stream().map(Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list)
```

Output:

```
[100, 200, 200, 750, 50, 500, 60]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you specified streams, but you don't actually need to use them.

Note that `Multimap` has a `keys()` method. This won't collapse duplicates (unlike the `keySet()` method). It returns a `Multiset` (aka Bag).

Code looks like:

```
Multiset<Long> keys = multiMap.keys();
```

And if you want a list (but it sounds like a `Multiset` suits your need):

```
List<Long> list = ImmutableList.copyOf(keys); // or new ArrayList<>(keys);

// [100, 200, 200, 750, 50, 500, 60]
System.out.println(list);
```